# Symfony2 non-mapped fields added in pre_set_data not present in form's children collection

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I am confused with a question related to non-mapped form fields (Symfony 2.6.6).

I have a form class based in my `Product` entity:

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('hidden1', 'hidden', array(
            'data' => 'Welcome hidden1!'
            'mapped' => false,
        ))
        ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $form->add('hidden2', 'hidden', array(
                'data' => 'Welcome hidden2!'
                'mapped' => false,
            ));
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form';
    }
}
```

If you look closely... I have added two non-mapped hidden fields:

- `hidden1` is added directly to `$builder->add(...)`
- ...but `hidden2` is added in [PRE_SET_DATA event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#a-the-formevents-pre-set-data-event).

Apparently both fields are identical (hidden and unmapped) and like [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) says:

> the data of an unmapped field can be accessed in a controller with:
>
> `$form->get('unmapped-field')->getData();`

Well...

Now, in `controllerOne` I create the form and pass my entity changing the action to `controllerTwo`:

```
public function controllerOneAction(Product $product, Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new productType(), $product, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('controller_two_route')
    ));
    return $form->createView();
}
```

ok, rendering the form (`{{ form(form) }}`) i can see my two hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_form_hidden1" name="my_form[hidden1]" 
    value="Welcome hidden1!">
<input type="hidden" id="my_form_hidden2" name="my_form[hidden2]" 
    value="Welcome hidden2!">
```

**CASE 1:**

In a different controller `controllerTwo` I want to validate this form. I create the form again, but this time I don't pass any entity (second null parameter):

```
public function controllerTwoAction(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new productType(), null);

    echo $form->get('hidden1')->getData(); // prints 'Welcome hidden1' in screen
    echo $form->get('hidden2')->getData(); // throw an exception... 
}
```

So that... trying to get `hidden2` in `$form` throws an exception (in ...Component/Form/Form.php at line 964) because `hidden2` is not present in form's children.

**CASE 2:**

However, **binding the form with an empty Product object (new Product())**, it works, why?.

```
public function controllerTwoAction(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new productType(), new Product());

    echo $form->get('hidden1')->getData(); // prints 'Welcome hidden1' in screen
    echo $form->get('hidden2')->getData(); // prints 'Welcome hidden2' in screen
}
```

Why in Case 1 `hidden1` is in form's children but `hidden2` isn't?

**Note**: I need to add `hidden2` in `pre_set_data` because the value is inside my `Product` entity, and this is (i think) the unique way to access my underlying entity.

Answer (score 3):

The PRE_SET_DATA event is called when you pass data to your form (the second parameter of createForm()). When you pass NULL, this event is not called.

The purpose of this event is to change form fields, according to the passed data, so there is no sense to use it without default data in your form.

Comment: thanks for your answer. That little detail is not mentioned in the documentation, I've spent hours so... thanks again.